# .htaccess redirection with multiple rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Basically what I want to do is :

1) redirect any .html request to .php page.

2) if any 404 happens , then it should redirect to www.domain.com

3) domain.com should be redirected to www.domain.com

4) www.domain.com/index.html should redirect to www.domain.com

Here is my htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^fr/(.)*$ / [R=301,NC,L]  # Added line
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule . http://www.domsdain.com/index.php [L] 
</IfModule> 


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

With above code 4th rule (www.domain.com/index.html should redirect to www.domain.com) is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor to use these rules:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.examle.com/
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.(?:php|html) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.examle.com/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^fr/(.)*$ / [R=301,NC,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.